# Error in json.loads() for data that has base64 decoding applied

Tags: python, json, utf-8, base64, decoding

I am trying to use json.loads() in python

I get the error:

### the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

```
a = {'h': '123', 'w': '12345', 'data': "b'eyJod2lkIjpwomfcwpvepovnepovqrepniLLKJAMSNDMSNDMAWEFMOEDAad='"}


a.update(json.loads(base64.b64decode(a['data'])))
```

Here the 'data' portion of a was being loaded in as a json dump with b64encoding.

```
'data':base64.b64encode(json.dumps(test).encode()); where test = some string eg('epovqrepniLLKJAMSNDMSNDMAWEFMOEDAad=')
```

I have tried using:

```
a.update(json.loads(base64.b64decode(a['data']).decode('utf-8')))
```

Giving me a 
    *'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position: invalid continuation byte*

I have also tried using **decodebytes** instead of **b64decode** to no avail.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: You don't need to json.loads(data=a) as it is already a python dict, you just need to output this dict directly. And outputing json string from a dict is json.dumps()'s job

Comment: The `data` value looks pretty corrupted. Do you know what `"b'eyJ...` was before it was encoded with JSON and B64? By removing the outer quotes and applying `b64decode` to the byte string `b'eyJ...'`, I get something that looks like JSON in the beginning (`b'{"hwid":`), but the remainder is clearly not valid JSON.

Comment: @lenz  you are correct, these were dummy values.
The actual encoded data was valid. I need to be able to remove the outer quotes in the dict. 
I am however, unable to use json,loads on the dict even though I used b64decode

Comment: Please show some actual (possibly abbreviated) values, so one can test a recovery strategy.

Comment: @lenz Apologies. There was sensitive data and I couldn't put it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

After lots of searching on Stackoverflow coupled with testing on my local machine I was able to drill it down to this.

The object `(a['data'])` that was being passed in had some values that were not utf-8 decodable.

It was in the form of `b'xxxsknoen'`

I ended up deleting the b and the quotes in the front and end and then converting it to an str.

```
var = base64.b64decode(str(a['data'])[2:-1]).decode('utf-8')
a.update(json.loads(var))
```