# Decoding JSON that contains Base64

Tags: python, json, python-requests, base64

I'm sending a request for a set of images to one of my API's. The API returns these images in a JSON format. This format contains data about the resource together with a single property that represents the image in Base64.

An example of the JSON being returned.

```
{
    "id": 548613,
    "filename": "00548613.png",
    "pictureTaken": "2020-03-30T11:38:21.003",
    "isVisible": true,
    "lotcode": 23,
    "company": "05",
    "concern": "46",
    "base64": "..."
}
```

[The correct content of the Base64](https://justpaste.it/python-base64-valid)
[The incorrectly parsed Base64](https://justpaste.it/python-base64-invalid)

This is done with the Python3 requests library. When i receive a successful response from the API i attempt to decode the body to JSON using:

```py
url = self.__url__(f"/rest/all/V1/products/{sku}/images")
headers = self.__headers__()
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    return r.json()
elif r.status_code == 404:
    return None
else:
    raise IOError(
        f"Error retrieving product '{sku}', got {r.status_code}: '{r.text}'")
```

Calling `.json()` results in the Base64 content being messed up, some parts are not there, and some are replaced with other characters. I tried manually decoding the content using `r.content.decode()` with the `utf-8` and `ascii` options to see if this was the problem [after seeing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693871/error-in-json-loads-for-data-that-has-base64-decoding-applied). Sadly this didn't work.
I know the response from the server is correct, it works with Postman, and calling `print(r.content)` results in a JSON document containing the valid Base64.

How would i go about de-serializing the response from the API to get the valid Base64?

Comment: @Trenton I assume you mean the Base64, sadly i cannot share it because i do not have ownership of the serialized resources.

Comment: @Harjan Take a random image of a duck. Convert it to base64. Put that base64 in a request like the one you provided and see if the problem arises. If yes, post that request so we can try.

Comment: @Trenton I have added some Base64, it should be a 1024x1024 picture of a pink and white box when parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import base64
import re
...
b64text = re.search(b"\"base64\": \"(?P<base>.*)\"", r.content, flags=re.MULTILINE).group("base")
decode = base64.b64decode(b64text).decode(utf-8)
```

Since you're saying "calling `print(r.content)` results in the valid Base64", it's just a matter of decoding the base64.

Comment: Good suggestion, i think this might have worked if it was just Base64 that was being returned. Calling this on my content results in the entire JSON response being decoded from Base64.

Comment: @Harjan then it's just a matter of extracting the base64 data from the text directly, see my answer for an example implementation.

Comment: I tried your edited solution. But calling `r.content` or `r.text` results in the same corrupted Base64. Extracting works, but parsing is not possible because it still contains the illegal characters.

Comment: @Harjan Check your content-type and charset, the default in requests is text/html, you can set a charset utf-8, that's probably not what your API is using, set the appropriate value using r.encoding and retry. Have you tried using urrlib and reproducing this behaviour?

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225035/serialize-in-json-a-base64-encoded-data

Comment: @PruthviRajReddy that's for serializing, not for deserializing, it's a bit more difficult, since you don't want to b64-decode the whole response, the correct approach is to take the response data in bytes (hopefully that's stored in valid base64) and deserialize it chunk by chunk using base64 decode.

Comment: @qedk Correct me if I'm wrong. The original response has both metadata and image content. I was pointing to string encode /serialize and send over network so that response received can be parsed form requests json directly and decode(des-serialize) the base64 value